# How to give acceptable values while creating a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

**ItemCategory Table**

ItemCategory - Primary key, Only accepts values S,M,C,D

CategoryName

is there any possible methods to create this table?
THANK YOU!

Comment: [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) as a posibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most recent versions of MySQL, you can use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table itemCategory add constraint check (categoryName in ('S', 'M', 'C', 'D'));
```